# Authentication from client side on node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, authentication, express, pug

I am using basic authentication on node.js + express.

The user can login with his/her credentials, and then, during the authentication phase I can store the username (as well as the password if I want to) in the request.user variable (see [basic authentication documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth)).

Now the authenticated user proceeds and sees the skeleton of the page with the aid of jade. Moreover, once the webpage has been loaded I want to perform various authenticated ajax calls in order to GET different resources. But here is a problem. I guess it would be OK when I render the page with jade to have something like this

```
index = function(req, res){
  res.user = req.user; // * see comment below
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
};
```

print the username on the page and fetch it with a jQuery command (because it is presented through jade in a specific object with a specific id). But doing the same thing for the password is clearly wrong.

I guess, my question is, how can the client in such a scenario figure out the username and password without rendering them on the page with jade?

Perhaps a good solution would be if I could exploit with jQuery the contents of the response that comes from the server and store them on the client side with something like:

```
 myUsername = res.user.username;
 myPassword = res.user.password;
```

Is something like this possible? How can I accomplish my goal? This should be a really easy question.

Comment: I am really looking for the easiest way to do it. The point is, that I can write down from the server side anything I want in the response (so, I can add variables), and the page that is served through jade really knows these things. But then when the document loads, I would like to fetch the username and the password that I passed to jade.

Comment: use the headers for this. Basic authentication only works through headers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication.